# try to fetch new generated event id with linq to sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

suppose i have 100 event id in my table (dbo.event), and currently i generate 101 event id
so i want to get only this event id(101) .i use linq to sql query for this.
here is my code.

```
protected void getDataforemail(int EventID,int ClientID)
{
        try
        {
            EventManagerDataContext db = new EventManagerDataContext();
            {
                var q = from a in db.EMR_EVENTs
                        join b in db.EMR_CLIENTs on a.ClientID equals b.ClientID

                        where a.ClientID == ClientID
                        orderby a.EventID descending 
                        select new
                        {
                            EventID = a.EventID,
                            Client_Name = b.Name,
                            Event_Name = a.Name,

                        }.Take(1);

                 q.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But this does not work for me, how can I fetch only newly generated `event_id` related data?

Comment: _"this does not work for me"_ Ok, but why? Btw, what is `q.ToString();`?

Comment: it return data....and covert into string.

Comment: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) i found this type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Take` on the sequence and not on the anonymous type, so you need to put the query in brackets:

```
var q = (from a in db.EMR_EVENTs
        join b in db.EMR_CLIENTs on a.ClientID equals b.ClientID

        where a.ClientID == ClientID
        orderby a.EventID descending 
        select new
        {
            EventID = a.EventID,
            Client_Name = b.Name,
            Event_Name = a.Name,

        }).Take(1);
```

Query syntax in C# doesn't support some methods like `Take` directly (as opposed to VB.NET which has language support for `Skip`, `Take`, `Distinct`, `Aggregate`).

Comment: hey but can you please tell me how i use return type. i use this way.         foreach (var order in q) 
  
                    { 
  
                       Console.WriteLine(order); 
  
                    }

Comment: @ketanitaliya: the query contains one anonymous type(note that you could also use `FirstOrDefault()` instead, then the type of the query would be an anonymous type instead of an `IEnumerable<anonymous type`). If you want to stay with `Take` and you want to output it: `var ev = q.FirstOrDefault();Console.Write("EventID:{0} Client_Name:{1} Event_Name:{2}", ev.EventID,ev.Client_Name,ev.Event_Name);`. Note that it can be `null` if the query didn't return one.